# jQuery: Saving a form with jQuery turns the form invalid

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, forms

I'd like to save a form containing an image.

Without jQuery the form saves as intended, however, adding below "`js-product_image-create-form`" function creates an invalid form, but, at the same time, json respond status is: `<JsonResponse status_code=200, "application/json">`

The form is invalid in the View (prints "invalid" below) and in "invalid" in jQuery.

However,

removing the `class="js-product_image-create-form"`, visually I get json with a `valid form = True` as well as the function prints `"valid"`

Why is the form valid in one case but invalid in the other case?

Using Django View:

```
def save_product_image_form(request, form, template_name):
    data = dict()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            data['form_is_valid'] = True
            print("valid")
            product_image = ProductImage.objects.all()
            data['html_product_image_list'] = render_to_string('product_image/includes/partial_product_image_list.html', {
                'product_image': product_image
            })
        else:
            data['form_is_valid'] = False
            print("invalid")
    context = {'form': form}
    data['html_form'] = render_to_string(
        template_name, context, request=request)
    return JsonResponse(data)


def product_image_create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProductImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    else:
        form = ProductImageForm()
    return save_product_image_form(request, form, 'product_image/includes/partial_product_image_create.html')
```

```js
$(function() {
  var saveForm = function() {
    var form = $(this);
    $.ajax({
      url: form.attr("action"),
      data: form.serialize(),
      type: form.attr("method"),
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        if (data.form_is_valid) {
          alert("I am valid");
          $("#product_image-table tbody").html(data.html_product_image_list);
          $("#modal-product_image").modal("hide");
        } else {
          alert("I am invalid !");
          $("#modal-product_image .modal-content").html(data.html_form);
        }
      }
    });
    return false;
  };
  $("#modal-product_image").on("submit", ".js-product_image-create-form", saveForm);
});
```

```html
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
<form method="post" action="{% url 'image_create' %}" class="js-product_image-create-form"
   enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Add a new Product Image</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    {% crispy form %}
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Add Product Image</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC, binary data (such as images) needs to be sent as multipart form data. If you want to send it as json, you'll have to base64 encode the image before sending it to the server, then decode the image on the server and save it using the storages api.

It works when you remove the class because jQuery is no longer controlling the form, and the data is instead sent synchronously to your `{% url 'image_create' %}` url using multipart (see your `action=` and `enctype=` html form attributes).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @kavdev answer to the question, I subsequently found an answer how to rectify the problem.

In this post [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56638046/10778349) @Musa also says that "*... ajax needs to use a FormData object to upload an image file.*" which results in below addition. This will renders the form as valid.
Only problem still though, I need to manually refresh the page to see the pictures again, but this is another question.

```
   var saveForm = function () {
      var form = $(this);
      var fd = new FormData(this);
      $.ajax({
         url: form.attr("action"),
         data: fd,
         type: form.attr("method"),
         dataType: 'json',
         processData: false,
         contentType: false,
         success: function (data) {
            if (data.form_is_valid) {
                alert("I am valid");
               $("#product_image-table tbody").html(data.html_product_image_list);
               $("#modal-product_image").modal("hide");
            } else {
                alert("I am invalid !");
               $("#modal-product_image .modal-content").html(data.html_form);
            }
         }
      });
      return false;
   };
```